# cursor focus is not blinking on windows phone text field

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have developed a Windows Phone app in which I have a login screen which accepts user name and password and a submit button.

Once user enters username and password and submtis, the user will be shown a home page which has a signout button in it.

From home page when user clicks on Signout button, the user will be redirected to login page.

Now in the login page the cursor focus is in text field but cursor is not blinking. I mean when I tap in the user name text box the keypad appears and I can enter the text.But cursor is not blicking.

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Is this on a physical device or the emulator? My emulator acts wonky at times.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to tap the textbox for the keypad to appear that means the focus is not on the textbox.

use the textbox1.Focus() to force focus on the textbox and the keypad automatically appears.

replace textbox1 with the name of your textbox

Comment: The issue is , Cursor not blinking when focus is set on textbox. Though I am able to set the text.

Comment: Does it stop blinking after logout, or everytime?

Comment: After every logout it stops blinking.I tested this on Phone as well as on Emulator.